# open file in "w" mode: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, file-io

When I try to open a file in **write** mode with the following code:

```
packetFile = open("%s/%s/%s/%s.mol2" % ("dir", "dir2", "dir3", "some_file"), "w")
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dir/dir2/dir3/some_file.mol2'
```

The `w` mode should create the file if it doesn't exist, right? So how can this error ever occur?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You'll see this error if the *directory* containing the file you're trying to open does not exist, even when trying to open the file in `w` mode.

Since you're opening the file with a relative path, it's possible that you're confused about exactly what that directory is. Try putting a quick print to check:

```
import os

curpath = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
packet_file = "%s/%s/%s/%s.mol2" % ("dir", "dir2", "dir3", "some_file")
print "Current path is: %s" % (curpath)
print "Trying to open: %s" % (os.path.join(curpath, packet_file))

packetFile = open(packet_file, "w")
```

Answer (score 21):

Since you don't have a 'starting' slash, your python script is looking for this file relative to the current working directory (and not to the root of the filesystem). Also note that the directories leading up to the file must exist!

And: use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine elements of a path.

e.g.: `os.path.join("dir", "dir2", "dir3", "myfile.ext")`

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error, but in my case the cause was, under Windows, a path longer than ~250 characters.

Comment: I also found it to be the windows path length problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check that that the script has write permissions on that directory. Try this:

```
chmod a+w dir/dir2/dir3
```

Note that this will give write permissions to everyone on that directory.

Comment: -1; this isn't a possible cause of the OP's error. If you don't have write permissions to the directory, Python will give you `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testdir/foo'`, not a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: This is a possible cause, if by "permissions" you mean "Windows Controlled folder access". Lots of programs will unhelpfully give no-such-file errors in this case instead of more logical permission-denied errors. Search "controlled folder access" in start and find python.exe in block history.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but my root cause was different than anyone's here.  Thought I'd share in case someone else ran into the same issue.

In my case, I had accidentally misplaced my parentheses on the 'with' line:

```
with (open(os.path.join(curpath, unique_name)), 'w') as fw:
```

Gave the following error (modified to obscure company details and for clarity):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./crap.py", line 60, in uniquify
    with (open(os.path.join(curpath, unique_name)), 'w') as fw:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/<mypath>/bin/python/<filename>'
```

These parentheses put the 'w' with the with() function, not with open() as intended.  I'm surprised it gives this IO Error, which implies it's something wrong with the open() call, which made this much harder to track down than if it obviously came from the with() call.

I didn't believe these results but just modified it again to replicate, and yes, I get the same error.

When I switch parentheses to the correct version:

```
with (open(os.path.join(curpath, unique_name), 'w')) as fw:
```

it works as intended.

Comment: You get an IO error because the problem is in fact within the `open()` call, as that is the one that doesn't get the correct arguments. `with` is perfectly fine, as you are just passing it a tuple.
To be clear: you don't need parenthesis with `with`, as it's not a method but a statement. When you do use parenthesis with multiple elements, it will get parsed as a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue happened in windows environment. Solution was to add "C:" to absolute path.
My goal was to save some files in user Desktop

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], os.path.join("Desktop", 
    "log_file.log_%s_%s" %(
    strftime("%Y_%m_%d", localtime()), "number_1")))
```

then I was  trying to open this directory to save 
such as

```
file_ref = open(file_path, "w")
```

I added this in order to run

```
file_ref = open(("C:\\"+file_path), "w")
```

Answer (score 1):

This error will also occur if you are trying to overwrite a broken soft link to a file with the same name. In that case, delete the broken soft link and you will be able to write the new file.

Comment: In my case, on Windows, the file I was trying to create was a restricted filename, "Com2.mp4" -- I guess MS-DOS restricts special names, and it can give this error. 

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-rename-a-folder-to-com-errorthe/ff48c793-ab97-4881-952a-df195321c11c